# Converting Geojson to kml using Python

Tags: python, geolocation, gis, geojson, kml

I can convert it kml/kmz to geojson also, creating kml from geojson..

I tried with the below libraries

```
Shapely
kml2geojson
geojson
```

Source code below..

```
import json
import simplekml


with open('file.geojson') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
kml = simplekml.Kml()
for feature in data['features']:
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
        kml.newpolygon(name=name,
                       description='test',
                       outerboundaryis=feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString':
        kml.newlinestring(name=name,
                          description='test',
                          coords=feature['geometry']['coordinates'])

    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Point':
        kml.newpoint(name=name,
                     description='test',
                     coords=[feature['geometry']['coordinates']])
kml.save('file.kml')
```

Comment: https://github.com/d-me3/json2kml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally can able to convert geojson file to kml using

```
import simplekml
```

```
import simplekml
import json

with open("myfile.geojson") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
kml = simplekml.Kml()
for feature in data['features']:
    geom = feature['geometry']
    geom_type = geom['type']
    if geom_type == 'Polygon':
        kml.newpolygon(name='test',
                       description='test',
                       outerboundaryis=geom['coordinates'][0])
    elif geom_type == 'LineString':
        kml.newlinestring(name='test',
                          description='test',
                          coords=geom['coordinates'])
    elif geom_type == 'Point':
        kml.newpoint(name='test',
                     description='test',
                     coords=[geom['coordinates']])
    else:
        print("ERROR: unknown type:", geom_type)
kml.save('kml_file.kml')
```

This working fine to me..

Comment: Hi @CodeMonkey, Kindly check the question and upvote?

Comment: Hi. You pasted the answer code into the question so now the answer doesn't add anything of value. A good question should be what you tried, what doesn't work, and what you expect.

Comment: But, you provided the solution for the question, It actually working for this as points.. The same what I expecting with linestring.. kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297543/12564020

Comment: Check answer to buffer all geom types [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428337/creating-buffer-spaces-in-meters-around-linestring-line-in-kml-using-python)